# Broadcast TCP-Server with libevent

Tags: tcp, libevent

I am looking for some sample code of a dead simple libevent-based TCP-Server which broadcasts incoming Messages to all connected clients. On the Web I only found TCP-Servers which echoes back messages.

One echo example if found is on the bottom of this page http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref8_listener.html

I am sure that its not so difficult to change the code provided on this Site, so that messages are brodcast to all connected clients, but I don't know how.

Could someone advise me?

EDIT: Yes, some kind of a chat server. It seams i need to do sth like this:

```
void server_read_cb(struct bufferevent *bev, void *data)
{
       struct evbuffer *input = bufferevent_get_input(bev);
       struct evbuffer *output = bufferevent_get_output(bev);

       char *mem = malloc(len); /* XXX: check for malloc failure */

       evbuffer_remove(input, mem, len);
       "for every connection conn" {
           /* XXX you'll need to implement a real connection list;
              the above isn't real C. */
               evbuffer_add(bufferevent_get_output(conn), mem, len);
       }
       free(mem);
}
```

But i can't put this to work.

Comment: Does a TCP-Server keep track of all open TCP-Clients that are connected to it at any given time? I would think that managing all of those connections would require more resources than simply broadcasting messages out on the "listen wire".

Comment: From looking at the sample code you linked, I'd *guess* the server has the option to record what devices are listening to it whenever a connection is made, then remove that device from the list of listeners whenever it receives an error on `accept_error_cb`. The `WangAFu` article seems to have left the particular implementation you seek up to the Programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want something similar to a chat server. One example is [here](http://klcommon.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/%20klcommon%20--username%20zmhn320@163.com/libevent/chatserver/). Basically, when you receive data from one connection, you just go through the list of connections and send that same data to each one (including/excluding the original).